# Tracing with `x-amzn-trace-id` of ALB without log

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

Let's say there are two servers. `server A` and `server B`.

Default process is below:
`server A` sends a request to the ALB and the ALB sends a request to `server B`.

The problem and the question is:
On `server A`, it got timeout error and there was a `x-amzn-trace-id` in header. But the results of querying the ALB logs with that `x-amzn-trace-id` was 0 row.
Can you explain the reason why I get 0 row from the query and how to trace the problem in this case?

I think after ALB generates `x-amzn-trace-id` when it gets incoming request from `server A`, it didn't log this request because it failed from `server B` by timeout error.

Comment: How exactly are you querying the ALB logs?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot With aws Athena, selecting from log table with `trace_id=#{MY_TRACE_ID_HERE}`

Comment: I assumed so but thought I should ask.  I would try downloading the logs from the bucket for the appropriate time window and grepping or inspecting them manually.  There is no reason I can think of this scenario not to create a log entry.  There is always the theoretical possibility of delayed or lost logs but that is rare... though it does take logs several minutes to appear, so I assume you are accounting for that.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the failure mode here. If the request didn't even reach the ALB (due to routing, security groups, WAFs, ...) you won't see it in the Access Logs.

If the request reached the ALB and the backend was unresponsive, you should get a different error code, e.g., HTTP 503, and that would show up in the logs.

Comment: Then if the request didn't reach the ALB, can `server A`(request server) have `x-amzn-trace-id`?

Comment: It depends, is this a header that Server A adds to the **request** or is it a header you're receiving in the **response**?

Comment: It's a header I'm receiving in the response from ALB

Comment: Then they should show up in the logs as Michael indicates above. Is this a consistent thing or is there just one trace missing?

Comment: It's consistent thing, at least ten trace are missed after starting alb logging